# Why JAX-RS @ApplicationPath is not working in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jax-rs

I have just bootstrap an Intellij JAX-RS project, but when trying to run I got an 404 to the "/api/hello-world" provided by the boilerplate code.

The HelloServlet works correctly on Tomcat 10, so I thing it may be something in the configs that Intellij may have not got me covered and I have no clues on how to fix it!

I tried to add the servlet section to web.xml (at the end of code blocks), but IDE complaints:
"'com.example.demo.HelloApplication' is not assignable to 'javax.servlet.Servlet,jakarta.servlet.Servlet'"

I got curious because I am not using "javax" but "jakarta":

Application:

```java
package com.example.demo;
    
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;
    
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {}
```

Resource:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello-world")
public class HelloResource {

  @GET
  @Produces("text/plain")
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}
```

Servlet (Working)

```java
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

  private String message;

  public void init() {
    message = "Hello World!";
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    // Hello
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
  version="5.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.demo.HelloApplication</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I tried the same project in javax (Tomcat 9) but the same happened, so no where to go from here.

Comment: WARNING: Tomcat is not a Jakarta EE application server. It's a barebones servlet container. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30176555 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65704617. Either use a normal JEE server or manually install JAX-RS in Tomcat.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't know the distinction. After your comment, I researched, and it seems possible if and only if building JAX-RS module. https://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat10/docs/cdi.html#JAX-RS_support

Answer (score 2):

As commented by BalusC Tomcat is not a JakartaEE (JavaEE) application server as Glassfish.

You can build Tomcat with JAX-RS and CDI support:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat10/docs/cdi.html#JAX-RS_support

However, there is a Tomcat project that already does that and more for you:

https://tomee.apache.org/

It is the same loved **Tomcat** + **Jakarta EE** support.

After installing TomEE Plume I got everything working like a charm.

If you got confused like me about what version to download in order to use JAX-RS, there is an interesting article available at https://www.tomitribe.com/blog/tomee-webprofile-vs-tomee-microprofile-vs-tomee-vs-tomee-plume/ that may clarify.

The author of the article says:

> TomEE PluME (pronounced plume) assists organizations that are
> migrating from Eclipse Glassfish to the Apache TomEE project. If you
> are not migrating from Glassfish to TomEE, you can ignore this
> distribution.

If you are not coming from Glassfish, you may try TomEE Plus as well.